# Python3 multiprocessing pool working on an objects method does not get updated data of object

Tags: python, dictionary, opencv, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I have openCV tracker objects that are getting updated. To make things faster I used multiprocessing pool with the map_async function to parallice the work. It works as expected I get a significant speed up. But 1 thing is strange / does not work. When I reinitialize my trackers with openCV (meaning giving them a new bounding box), the tracker is not updated but continues with the previous bounding box. This only happens when using the multiprocessing pool but does not happen when using a sequential loop over the tracker list. I suspect that the process makes its own copy of the tracker object and thus the reinitialization of the tracker does not apply to that newly created object. However to my understanding when I call the function map_async a new process is created and with process.wait() it is waiting until that process finished its work.

I already tried to create a new pool everytime I call my updateTrackers() function. That did not solve the problem.

Working reinitialization sequential code:

```
    def updateTrackers(self, frame):
        for t in self.trackers:
            t.update()
```

Not working reinitialization sequential code:

```
    def updateTrackers(self, frame):
        processes = []
        # create a process for each tracker
        for t in self.trackers:
            processes.append(self.ProcessPool.map_async(t.update, (frame, )))

        # wait for the processes to finish
        for p in processes:
            p.wait()
```

The code for reinitializing the tracker object is the same in both cases:

```
    def reInitTracker(self, index, frame):
        if index >= self.nmbTrackers:
            return

        initBB = cv2.selectROI("Camera view", frame, fromCenter=False,
                showCrosshair=True)
        self.trackers[index].tracker.clear()
        self.trackers[index].tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        self.trackers[index].tracker.init(frame, initBB)
```

EDIT:
I just found out that the trackers do not get updated when parallelising them. Which is more consistent now with them also not getting initialized.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue the `t` (tracker) object is not getting updated when you pass `t.update` as the worker function in your call to `map_async`

Yes, `t` will be serialized/deserialized to the multiprocessing pool for execution of the `update` method and if `t`'s state is modified by `update` it will not be reflected back to the main process. As an aside, it is rather unusual to call a map method with an *iterable* argument  consisting of  single element as you are doing; `apply_async` would be more appropriate.

The solutions is for your `update` method (not shown by you, unfortunately) to return `self` and to then update the tracker object in the main process with this return value:

```py
    def updateTrackers(self, frame):
        results = [self.ProcessPool.apply_async(t.update, (frame,)) for t in self.trackers]
        # It is assumed that t.update now returns with t.self
        # It is also assumed that self.trackers is a list or otherwise indexable:
        for idx, result in enumerate(results):
            # Wait for task to finish and update tracker with returned value:
            self.trackers[idx] = result.get()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes that looks like a solution at first, I found out that myselfe, but the problem with that is that the multiprocessing library cannot pickle objects. For that reason  I did some research and found that one can use the Pathos (https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos) fork of the multiprocessing library. However I still have the same pickle error: "TypeError: cannot pickle 'cv2.TrackerKCF' object. It seems like something went wrong with the installation of the dependencies of the Pathos module. ...

Comment: *In general*, of course, the multiprocessing library *can* pickle objects -- maybe just not *your* object. But what I don't get is if your worker function is `t.update`, you have to be able to pickle `t` from the main process to the processing pool to execute the `update` method. So is `update` adding an attribute that did not exists originally in `t` that now makes it incapable of being picked for the purposes of returning it? This is the problem when you don't post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Refering to your BooBoos comment:

No the update method does not add any attribute. And you are right, that is indeed strange. I created a minimal, reproducable example which causes the same error:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool

tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
Pool = ProcessPool()

# dummy values
frame = np.array((100,100,3))
initBB = (1,2,3,4)
tracker.init(frame, initBB)

p = Pool.apipe(tracker.update, frame)
p.get()
```

The problem seems to be the get method

Comment: I just happened to stumble upon this "answer" (which really should be an update to your question that provides more details since this does not resolve your question) because you never replied to my comment on *my* answer so I was not aware of this. Now I see that you left out in your original post a non-trivial detail, namely you are not even using either  multiprocessing package from the standard Python library but rather `pathos`, about which I know nothing, This is why you should *always* post a minimal, reproducible example at the outset.